# Unicode Character U+0972 seems to be broken while rendering normally

Tags: support, unicode, rendering

See this question on Ask Ubuntu: [What are the key combinations for alphabets 'ऋ' and 'ॲ' on Hindi Bolnagari keyboard layout?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/277845/what-are-the-key-combinations-for-alphabets-and-on-hindi-bolnagari-keybo)

I am talking about [Unicode Character 'DEVANAGARI LETTER CANDRA A' (U+0972)](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/972/index.htm). There seems to be rendering issues with it. The character displays perfectly fine in the raw input (ie; the body, title, comments - all in edit mode) but doesn't render correctly when posted. This happens everywhere - title, body, comments.

Examples: `ॲ` renders correctly in inline code but it is displayed as ॲ normally.

```
ॲ is also displayed correctly in Code Block
```

Wrapping it in `<kdb>` tag renders it correctly on AU but not on Meta.SO -- <kbd>ॲ</kbd>.

This is how it looks at my end:

> [image: its look at my end]

I am using Firefox 19.0.2 on Ubuntu. Character Encoding is already selected as Unicode (UTF - 8). Is it happening only to me?

Comment: Works for me. Chrome Stable on Ubuntu 12.04.

Comment: @Manishearth: Yes.. Just tested myself on Chrome.. Works well at my end too.... Looks like the problem is with Firefox...

Comment: Works for me on FF 19.0.2 on Ubuntu as well. I haven't installed any extra fonts except those that you get prompted about during the installation/updates.

Comment: @Manishearth: I haven't installed any other fonts as well.. I would upload the image of how it renders for me.

Comment: Looks fine on IE

Comment: Looks fine here

Comment: Works for me on FF 20.

Comment: Works for me on FF 19.0.2, Windows 7.

Answer (score 2):

Encoding is not the problem, since you see the character in some instances.

The problem is clearly in the font your browser is using and in particular:

- It works when matching `Consolas, Menlo, Monaco, 'Lucida Console', 'Liberation Mono', 'DejaVu Sans Mono', 'Bitstream Vera Sans Mono', 'Courier New', monospace, serif;`
- It fails when matching `Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;`
- It fails again when matching `Arial, 'Liberation Sans', 'DejaVu Sans', sans-serif;`

The problem is likely to be the default fonts on Firefox, which you can change - or you can install [Microsoft fonts](https://askubuntu.com/questions/55643/install-ms-truetype-fonts-system-wide-for-all-users) or Apple fonts.

For more info: [(Ubuntu -Firefox- default font) How make default font arial in Firefox on Ubuntu 10.04?](https://superuser.com/questions/143051/ubuntu-firefox-default-font-how-make-default-font-arial-in-firefox-on-ubuntu)

Comment: I followed AskUbuntu's link and installed `ttf-mscorefonts-installer`. Thereafter changed the default font in Firefox to Arial. [See the image](http://i.stack.imgur.com/EuxqA.png). However, I still face this problem. It didn't have any effect whatsoever. Do I need to make further changes using the Advanced option for Fonts? If so, what should I use?

Answer (score 0):

This means that either your browser isn't reading the page with the right encoding or your system doesn't have a font with that character.

Comment: I have checked the encodings. BTW, encoding and fonts shouldn't matter at all since the Unicode Character renders perfectly fine when used inside inline code or a code block. See the image that I have uploaded in question.

Comment: Encoding does matter as the surrounding `<pre>` blocks help the browser separate the byte sequences.

Comment: I have UTF - 8 already selected as encoding (this is already default on Firefox). See the image: http://i.stack.imgur.com/EabUG.png