# Browse Field in Image Dialog is too large in Firefox

Tags: bug, status-declined, user-interface, images, firefox

### Using Firefox on Ubuntu

Browse field is browsing around - happens on SO and its Meta, Security.SE and its Meta - I have accounts on them and have verified them myself. Also happens on Super User, Server Fault, Tex.SE, Math.SE and probably many others as well - couldn't test their Meta as I don't have an account there.

[image: bug-in-SO-image-dialog]

Works just right on Ask Ubuntu and its Meta, Unix.SE and its Meta - couldn't find any other site which worked well.

[image: AU-image-dialog-just-about-ok]

### Using Chrome on Ubuntu

Seems to work well on all the sample sites I tested.

[image: chrome-works-well]

### Further Testing

1. **Doesn't work:**

   - Works well on other OS and browsers. Problem seems to be specific to Firefox (any version) on Ubuntu (any version). Tested FF 16.0.1 on Ubuntu 12.10, FF 18.0.2 on Ubuntu 12.04.2, FF 20.0 on Ubuntu 13.04. (Little odd, that the image dialog works well only for Ask Ubuntu and Unix.SE ;-))
2. **Works Well:**

   - Firefox 20.0 on Windows 8 - No problem.
   - Firefox 17.0.1 on Fedora 18 - No problem.
   - Chrome on Ubuntu and Windows 8 - No problem.

Comment: What operating system? Do you happen to have your fonts not set to default sites for SO on FF?

Comment: @Oded: Ubuntu.. Don't know about Fonts. I am also facing this issue: [Unicode Character U+0972 seems to be broken while rendering normally](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/175178/unicode-character-u0972-seems-to-be-broken-while-rendering-normally) - are they related. Am I the only one facing this?

Comment: The two are not related. I was asking about default font size (use `Ctrl + 0` to reset size) - is what you are seeing happening with this size? Also, what version of Ubuntu?

Comment: @Oded: Yes. It's still happening after `Ctrl + 0`. Right now using Ubuntu 13.04.

Comment: @Aditya I think the solution is to use Internet Explorer 6.0 on Windows XP.

Comment: I can confirm this with **Firefox 20.0 on Ubuntu 12.10 64-bit**. I noticed the problem on Stack Apps as well.

Comment: I am unable to reproduce using Linux Mint with Firefox 20 (Mint is based on Ubuntu).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We will not fix this.

The issue is in a specific combination of OS and browser,  and at that browser that is known to be um... unusual when it comes to how it styles the file input control.

It is a minor display issue as well and is not causing any functional problem in using the image upload feature.

Comment: True, site can't be expected to support all possible browsers.

Comment: @ShaWizDowArd - Well, we are also not supporting IE 8 and under.

Comment: @Oded: But why is it so that the bug is not present on Ask Ubuntu and Unix.SE - the image dialog renders perfectly fine on those two SE sites? (I do agree that its a minor issue and doesn't affect much if its fixed or not).

Comment: @Aditya - Not sure. I have not spent much time investigating it, but it is likely due to some custom CSS on those two sites.

Comment: @Aditya - Well, that's our answer. Yes, it is a bug. No, we are not fixing it...

Comment: @Oded: The bug seems to be fixed and now it is consistent across all the sites I frequently visit. Should the tag for this question be changed to [meta-tag:status-completed]?

Comment: @Aditya - this seems to come back every now and then. Chances are that either a FireFox or some library update in your distribution of choice is why it is working OK, nothing we did.

Comment: @Oded: I do think there were changes on your part; now the Browse button and field in Firefox is also like the one in Chrome (see the images of how it were earlier in my question)... Anyways, I don't know much about these stuff, so it's upto you if tags need to be changed or not :-)